# OpenVPN Site-to-Site Routing

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've been trying to set up an OpenVPN site-to-site tunnel for 2 days and I'm currently stuck with the following problem. :/

With the current configuration I can reach all servers in the client network from the server LAN network.
From the server on which the OpenVPN client is running I can also access the servers in the server LAN.
But now I want to extend the connection so that the other servers in the client network have access to the server network. The OpenVPN client should serve as a gateway.

**Examples:**

10.12.1.21--> 10.10.10.30 --> works 
10.10.10.30  --> 10.12.1.21 --> no connection 
10.12.1.21--> 10.10.11.105 --> works 
10.10.11.105 --> 10.10.10.30 --> works \

**Network**:

*Server:*

LAN NETWORK: 10.12.0.0/16 
OpenVPN LAN IP: 10.12.1.10 (default GW for all Servers in 10.12.0.0/16 network) 
OpenVPN Tunnel IP: 10.3.100.1

*Client:*

LAN NETWORKS: 10.10.10.0/24, 10.10.11.0/24 
OpenVPN LAN IP: 10.10.11.105 (no default gw) 
OpenVPN Tunnel IP: 10.3.100.2

*Client router config:*

Destination     Gateway       
10.12.0.0/16    10.10.11.105

**Server**:

```
dev ovpns2 
verb 3 
syslog 
dev-type tun 
script-security 3 
daemon 
keepalive 10 60 
ping-timer-rem 
persist-key 
proto udp4 
cipher AES-256-CBC 
auth SHA256 
up /usr/sbin/ovpn-up 
down /usr/sbin/ovpn-down 
lport 1196 
management /var/run/openvpn/server4.sock unix 
multihome 
secret /etc/openvpn/server4.secret 
persist-tun 
route-metric 20 
ifconfig 10.3.100.1 10.3.100.2 
max-clients 1 
route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 
route 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0 
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-CBC
```

**Client**:

```
dev ovpnc2 
verb 3 
dev-type tun 
script-security 3 
local 10.10.11.105 
persist-tun 
persist-key 
cipher AES-256-CBC 
auth SHA256 
ifconfig 10.3.100.2 10.3.100.1 
remote 85.158.X.X 1196 udp4 
keepalive 10 60 
route 10.12.0.0 255.255.0.0 
ncp-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-256-CBC:AES-128-CBC 
resolv-retry infinite 
lport 0 
secret vpn-S2S.secret
```

**Client IP Tables:**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.11.105 (OpenVPN Client IP)
```

Thanks for the help!